# Combine JQuery AutoComplete with radio buttons in li element of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, autocomplete

This is my code:

```
$('.SliderBox').on("focus",function () {            
            $(this).autocomplete({
                delay: 500,
                minLength: @(Model.SearchTermMinimumLength.ToString()),
                source: '@(Url.RouteUrl("ProductSearchAutoComplete"))',
                select: function( event, ui ) {                    
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    var box_id = $(this).closest('.search-box').attr('value');
                    $('.Picture'+box_id+' img').attr('src',ui.item.productpictureurl[0]).width(100).height(100);
                    $('#Picture'+box_id+'Id').attr('value',ui.item.PicId)
                    $('.Text'+box_id+' input').attr('value',ui.item.label)
                    $('.Link'+box_id+' input').attr('value',ui.item.producturl);
                    return false;
                }
            })
                            .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) { 

                                var divClass = item.label + "-class";
                                divClass = divClass.replace(/\s+/g, '');   

                                var radioBtn = '<input type="radio" name="'+item.label+'" />';

                                var li = $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item);
                                li.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");                                

                                li.append("<div class = '"+divClass+"' ></div>");  
                                li.appendTo(ul);                                
                                for(var i = 0; i<item.productpictureurl.length; i++){    
                                    $("." + divClass).append("<img width='100px' height='100px' src='" + item.productpictureurl[i] + "' />");
                                    $("." + divClass).append(radioBtn);
                                }                                

                                //li.appendTo(ul);
                                return li;
                            };
        });
```

This is a result of this code: 
[image]
I can't click on radio button (when I try - autocomplete select start working). When I remove tag `a` from this line: `li.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>");` I was able to select `radiobutton`. How I can resolve it? I just need to select radiobutton and then click on `<a>`.